# Джанго не может найти путь к привязке. Текст ошибки: The current path, to_write, didn't match any of these

Tags: django

```
     `urls.py: 
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
        path('<int:history_id>/', views.detail, name = 'detail'),
        path('<int:history_id>/leave_comment/', views.leave_comment, name = 'leave_comment'),
        path('<int:to_write>/', views.to_write ,name = 'to_write'),

]`



 views.py:
def to_write(request):
        return render(request, 'history/list.html')


list.html:
{% extends 'to_write.html'%}

{% block title%}Напиши историю своих предков!{% endblock %}

{% block content %} Lorem Ipsum{% endblock %}

to_write.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>{% block title%}{% endblock %}</title>
</head>
<body>
    {%block content%}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

единственное, что  можно предположить, из того  что вы скинули это  надо исправить

```
path('<int:to_write>/', views.to_write ,name = 'to_write')
```

на

```
path('to_write/', views.to_write ,name = 'to_write')
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @ЯрославПрокофьев не за что.
если не сложно, отметьте ответ на вопрос)